# What vs That or Which in dependent and independent clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, subordinate-clauses

I know this may sound strange but I've heard people use **what** instead of **that** or **which** in dependent and independent clauses a lot of times. I was trying to search for why they do it but couldn't find the right grammar; however, there are plenty of examples. Is it a normal thing or maybe there are cases where **that** or **which** can't be used?

- I think it's time we close the meeting. If there is anything else what has to be discussed, please tell me.
- I think our work here is over. Remember that all what has been done today has a purpose.
- Sometimes what I tell you doesn't have to be taken head-on, those are words of advice.

Comment: "What" is not ordinarily allowed in relative clauses in Standard English, so your first two examples are ungrammatical. Your third example, though, is okay. It's a 'fused' relative construction where, crucially, " what I tell you" is a noun phrase headed by the fused relative word "what", whose meaning is "that which".

Comment: @BillJ So we can place **that which** instead and the meaning shouldn't change?

Comment: Yes, that's right -- or "the thing which" -- whichever you prefer. (Only in your 3rd example, of course!)

Comment: @SovereignSun this could be a dialect.  It sounds familiar to me, but without the accent I couldn't tell you which dialect it's from.  As a dialect it's not *wrong* but it would sound odd to the average English speaker.